# Parsing a python string into a JSON file

Tags: python

I need to parse a string from a python function into json.dump() but I can't find a solution to remove the quotation marks from the string after it's written into the JSON.

I have this:

```
"[{'number1':1, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'},{'number1':2, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'}]"
```

And I need this:

```
[{'number1':1, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'},{'number1':2, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'}]
```

I tried to strip it using `str.strip('""')` but the quotation marks stay and a few different things from other threads similar to my problem but none have worked

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do or is that impossible?

Code:

```py
def batchStr(batchIds, count1, count2 ,status):
    seg1 = "{'batchId':"
    seg2 = ",  'source1count': "
    seg3 = ",  'source2count': "
    seg4 = ", 'status':"
    seg5 = "},"
    str1 = "["
    for id in range(len(batchIds)):
        str2 = str(seg1)+str(batchIds[id])+str(seg2)+str(count1[id])+str(seg3)+str(count2[id]+str(seg4)+str(status[id])+str(seg5)
        str1 = str(str1) + str(str2)
    str1 = str1[:-1]+"]"
    return str1
```

I want it to output to the JSON like that:

```
[{'batchId':1,  'source1count': 100,  'source2count': 100, 'status':success},...]
```

But it outputs:

```
"[{'batchId':1,  'source1count': 100,  'source2count': 100, 'status':success},...]"
```

Comment: Show us the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the quotemarks you are seeing are just python informing you that the data you are displaying is a string (this will happen if you are using the repl or a jupyter notebook).

Regardless, here is a cleaned up version of your code that outputs what you are looking for

```py
import json

def batchStr(batchIds, count1, count2 ,status):
    json_array = [
        dict(
            batchId=bid,
            source1count=c1,
            source2count=c2,
            status=s
        )
        for bid, c1, c2, s in
        zip(batchIds, count1, count2, status)
    ]
    return json.dumps(json_array)

print(batchStr([1,2,3], [100]*3, [200]*3, ["success"]*3))
```

Outputs:

```
[{"batchId": 1, "source1count": 100, "source2count": 200, "status": "success"}, {"batchId": 2, "source1count": 100, "source2count": 200, "status": "success"}, {"batchId": 3, "source1count": 100, "source2count": 200, "status": "success"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clean up both of my code and my question however it doesn't solve my problem as I want to input that string into another function that then creates the json file with some additional info. Also parameters in the function are all lists taken from another function so it needs to be "flexible"

Comment: @Bartus it has the same api as your function so it should be compatible. If you want to add extra information, I recommend passing around python data structures (like a dictionary or list) to do so, then your "write to json" function can serialize the data when it has everything it needs. Trying to half serialize data always ends in sadness.

Comment: @Bartus im also getting from your comment that you are taking the output from this function, then adding it to another object to be passed into `json.dumps`. Thats exactly why you are getting the extra quotemarks. You are serializing this json as a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: would passing it as a list help?

Comment: @Bartus I would assume so. Though its hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: '
    def BatchCountsStr(batchIds, count1, count2, status):
    seg1 = "'batchId':"
    seg2 = ",  'source1count': "
    seg3 = ",  'source2count': "
    seg4 = ", 'status':"
    list = []
    for id in range(len(batchIds)):
        str2 = "
{"+str(seg1)+str(batchIds[id])+str(seg2)+str(count1[id])+str(seg3)+str(count2[id])+str(seg4)+str(status[id])+"}"
        list.append(str2)
    return list
'

Comment: @Bartus You are still attempting to serialize the data to json before you are writing it, so you will have the same issue. If you take my answer and change `return json.dumps(json_array)` to just `return json_array`, it should work so long you arent doing the same half-seralization in other places.

Comment: Forgive my non-functioning brain, I dont have a clue how editing works here

Comment: Sure thing let me try

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your list in string format to list first, try using eval(list).
Then, you could do json.dumps(list) and write it into the file.

Comment: This solution generates an error code:
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.Name object at 0x0000023BDC5325C0>

Answer (score -1):

To use the strip string function you need the backslash escape character for the quotation character.

```
str = "[{'number1':1, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'},{'number1':2, 'number2': 2, 'number3': 3, 'word1': 'word'}]" 
solution = str.strip('\"')
print(solution)
```

Or you can use RE regular expression.

Comment: That won't do it, the double quotes aren't actually part of the string.  It's just Python's way of indicating it's a string.

Comment: I tried strip('""') before and it didin't strip the quotations and strip('\"') gives me literally nothing, just the quotation marks